# UIPageViewController & UIPageContentViewController + MapKit Lag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use CoreLocation and MapKit to show a MapView on a certain PageViewController

Basically, when you go to the new page and it isn't loaded, there is a serious FPS drop.

Code is available at: http://hastebin.com/yuwuqujuto.py

**DISCLAIMER: I'm kind of new to this, so any other findings with code efficiency would be awesome!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the nature of the beast. MapKit has to ask the location manager for your location, then it has to ask the server for the map tiles that describe your location. Then those tiles need to be downloaded over the network, processed, and displayed. It might take 10 seconds or longer.

You'll see the same thing with Apple's Maps application when it needs to display new content.

Comment: It'd go faster with in a block (theoretically), but I can't seem to load the Map View in a block.

Comment: I don't believe putting it within a block will magically increase the network speed. :)

Comment: @user3477144 said "It'd go faster with in a block (theoretically)". Nope. Blocks don't make code faster. Plus, the process of requesting and displaying map contents is network i/o bound, not CPU-bound. Even if it did speed up the processing, it doesn't help to speed up a part that isn't causing the delay in the first place.

Comment: @troop231 I meant that the FPS lag when swiping to that page would go away, but I guess you're right.